# How I can set option value from select form to extbase controller

Tags: typo3, extbase

In fluid I have select form

```
<f:form action="cityList" controller="City">
    <f:form.select
        class="js-select"
        property="city" 
        name="cityId" 
        options="{cityList}" 
        optionLabelField="title" 
        optionValueField="uid" />
    <f:form.submit value="Submit" />
</f:form>
```

In controller

```
/**
 * action city list
 *
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function cityListAction()
{

    $cityList = $this->cityRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('cityList', $cityList);      

    $cityData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'citySessionData', $cityId);
    $cityData = $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'citySessionData');
    echo $cityData;
}
```

But I don't have any data. If I set manual $cityId, I have session data. How I can set city id from form to $cityId

Answer (score 0):

Your  is not bound to an object so the  cannot use the propery property="city" correctly. Your listAction is also not expecting to get any parameters passed to it.

Please change the ViewHelpers accordingly:

```
<f:form action="cityList" controller="City" objectName="filter" object="{filter}">
  <f:form.select
        class="js-select"
        property="cityId" 
        options="{cityList}" 
        optionLabelField="title" 
        optionValueField="uid" />
    <f:form.submit value="Submit" />
</f:form>
```

In the HTML output, the select field should become a name like `name="tx_yourext_yourplugin[filter][cityId]"`. This is very important because otherwise the form values wont be submitted to your action.

Then change your Action:

```
/**
 * action city list
 * @param array $filter
 * @return void
 */
public function cityListAction($filter = [])
{

    $cityList = $this->cityRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('cityList', $cityList);
    // Give $filter back to view so it will stay selected
    $this->view->assign('filter', $filter); 


    $cityData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', 'citySessionData', $filter['cityId']);
    $cityData = $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'citySessionData');

    // You shall not use echo in TYPO3
    // echo $cityData; 
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($cityData);
}
```

**I did not test this!**

After changing the action you must clear the cache using the installtool or reinstall the extension.

Comment: Thanks its works, session is setting. But if I want to get session after browsing in this controller or in another controller like $cityData = $GLOBALS["TSFE"]->fe_user->getKey('ses', 'citySessionData'); my variable is empty. And session stored in table fe_session_data

Comment: A session is bound to a cookie which is bound to a domain. After setting the session, check your cookies for domain and lifetime.

Comment: Can I ask if this method still relevant to Typo3 V8+? From what I have read the "property" and 'name="tx_yourext_yourplugin[filter][cityId]"' thing no longer seems to apply as all recent examples utilise "$this->request->hasArgument" instead